# Stripe payment: pre-checkout step

Tags: stripe-payments

Stripe provides rich UI elements - their checkout page is awesome. Products, subscriptions, discounts could be defined on stripe side and even don't need to worry about all of that mechanics. I am a bit confused about pre-checkout page where user can select a product, play with quantities, try to apply coupon code and see final price. I did not find that UI element in their documentation, but it is really boring to build such type of page and repeat all of that mechanics. Are there any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Subscriptions, you can use [Pricing table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table). You can find all Stripe no-code options in this [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/no-code). However for one-time products/prices you need to build your own UI/UX.